# XLST - Split Long address into multiple tag based on length nicely

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a XML stylesheet transformation where it required to split a long text into multiple tags.
It need to split based on max length of 10 nicely where it will stop when the next character unable to fit into current line.

Any advises on this?

For example:

Before:

```
<main>
   <header>
      <addresses>aaaaaaa bbbb cccc e ffffffff ggggg hhhh</addresses>
   </header>
</main>
```

After:

```
<main>
   <header>
      <address>aaaaaaa</address>
      <address>bbbb cccc</address>
      <address>e ffffffff</address>
      <address>ggggg hhhh</address>
   </header>
</main>
```

Comment: what have you already tried to do this?

Comment: What does "split based on max length of 10 nicely" mean exactly? Your input has three `c`s and two `d`s, why does the output have four `c`s and no `d`? Have you looked into the `analyze-string` function in XSLT 3 or the `xsl:analyze-string` element in XSLT 2?

Comment: Hi Greenev, I have tried to use tokenize but it only allow for delimiter.

Comment: Hi Martin Honen, Sorry for confusing, I have updated my question.

Comment: What should happen if one of the "words" is more than 10 characters long? (i.e. "zzzzzzzzzzzz").

Comment: Hi Tim C, it will be splitted by forced. For example, zzzzzzzzzzzz will be come zzzzzzzzzz and zz

Comment: Is white space treated the same as letters?

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="addresses">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitSequence">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="splitSequence">
        <xsl:param name="input" />
        <addresses><xsl:value-of select="substring($input,1,10)" /></addresses>
        <xsl:if test="substring($input,10+1)">
            <xsl:call-template name="splitSequence">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input,10+1)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output is**

```
<main>
<header>
    <addresses>aaaaaaa bb</addresses>
    <addresses>bb cccc e </addresses>
    <addresses>ffffffff g</addresses>
    <addresses>gggg hhhh</addresses>
</header>
```

Comment: Is It? Where is the "nicely" part?

Comment: @michael.hor257k sir I have search text length 10 then split the text.